# GCP: Bucket Creation in Go

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, bucket, kubernetes-go-client

I'm trying to create a bucket in GCP using Go, I tried this [create](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/storage/buckets/main.go#L101-L112) method, that creates a bucket in Go. Here's the  [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mhYtJxYlCQT) of the same. When I try to run it, it just says
`timeout running go build` and `Go Build Failed`. I know it's trying to download some packages, but not sure why it is getting timed out while downloading the package?.
I'm new to Go and wanted to test out how bucket creation works in go. Am I missing something?.

Comment: Please show the commands you run to build you program. And why are you using a kubernetes client?

Comment: @Marc the reason why I'm using a Kubernetes client is because I will be creating a bucket in Kubernetes Cluster that is deployed on GCP.

Comment: @Marc but right now, I'm more concerned about why this code is not working at all?. It should throw an error, do something, it just says timeout because the packages weren't downloaded. Can you try it once locally from your end?. Save this as a go file and run using go run <filename.go> ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Create this `create-bucket.go` file and replace the project ID with your project ID:

```
// Sample storage-quickstart creates a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    // Sets your Google Cloud Platform project ID.
    projectID := "<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>"

    // Creates a client.
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
    }

    // Sets the name for the new bucket.
    bucketName := "go-new-bucket"

    // Creates a Bucket instance.
    bucket := client.Bucket(bucketName)

    // Creates the new bucket.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*10)
    defer cancel()
    if err := bucket.Create(ctx, projectID, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create bucket: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Bucket %v created.\n", bucketName)
}
```

Run the go file that you created in the previous step:

```
go run create-bucket.go
```

You'll find the `go-new-bucket` under the [GCP storage menu](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Neo, is there's any way to do it without installing/setting up the `gcloud` CLI?. I have my gcloud console open in the browser.

Comment: You're welcomed. What do you mean by _gcloud console_? You can use the Google Cloud Shell, if you want to do it from the browser. On the top right corner if the GCP web portal, there's an icon **Activate Cloud Shell**. gcloud CLI is installed by default in there

Comment: I meant that I have my https://console.cloud.google.com/ already open in the browser, instead of setting the gcloud CLI first and logging in from the CLI and then running the go code, is there's any way we can directly run this go code without the gcloud CLI?
Or is it not possible at all without the gcloud CLI?.

Comment: You must provide authentication credentials to your application code by setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. The easiest way to achieve this is using `gcloud auth application-default login`. If you want to do it manually, you'll need to read and understand how the GCP IAM works: First you need to generate a key.json, copy the key on the machine that is executing your go app, then `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/my-key.json`

Comment: One more question, is there's any way we can run this piece of code standalone?. I mean not on the cloud but just standalone?. Since we are calling the gcloud's API, is there's anyway just to check if the bucket is being created standalone?. Without any GCP cluster running in real-time.

Comment: Can you please define what you understand by _GCP cluster_ and _real-time_?

Comment: Like imagine running a hello-world.go file?. The command for that will be `go run hello-world.go`, in that same way, can we run `go run bucket-creation.go ` and expect some output based on that?. Check my go playground, is there's any way to run that just like that without anything else and simply running that file?

Comment: GCP cluster -> A Kubernetes Cluster running over GCP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219870/discussion-between-rajat-singh-and-neo-anderson).

Comment: The Kubernetes cluster has nothing to do with the bucket that you are creating. You can run that go file even on your local computer.